# Why posting meta requires only 5 reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta, privileges

#### Why posting meta requires only 5 reputation? Why not something like 25 or more with the requirement of having some particular badges?

A new user automatically gets 1 reputation. So, to get privilege for posting on Meta requires only 4 reputation. So, new users can easily access Meta and ask useless questions about this site as they don't know much about this site. Many new users even not have the Informed badge but have privilege to post on Meta. Some just scroll the tour page to just earn the Informed badge.

#### Shouldn't we increase the requirement of posting on Meta so questions on Meta have more quality?

#### Shouldn't we set that users must have some bronze badge to post here to ensure that they know fundamentals of this site?

Comment: "new users can easily access Meta" Isn't that the point? This is where they come for help to learn the site. Meta is far less strict when it comes to question quality and we really do not have an issue useless questions here. If the only reason to change the requirements is people might ask useless questions, 20 rep won't change that. I would say that the only reason it is even 5 is because it makes this site almost 100% spam free. Not to mention more users would post for site help on main, meaning someone has to clean it up and move it here anyway.

Comment: @MarkKirby, shouldn't this be an Answer rather than a Comment?

Comment: @RayButterworth Sure, will change it to an answer in a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may have a bit of a misunderstanding about what Meta is for, it is not a special place for advanced users to discuss but a help site (just like main) for Ask Ubuntu.

> "new users can easily access Meta"

Sure they can, that is the point. Meta is where people can come and ask questions about the main site and new users are the demographic most in need of that help.

> "Why posting meta requires only 5 reputation? Why not something like
>   25 or more"

The reason for the 5 rep requirement is to stop spam posts and it works close to 100%, I can't remember the last spam I saw here, it is not to restrict access to low rep users.

I don't think making it 25 or even 100 rep would bring the quality up, this site is low traffic (1 post a day even?) and as a result is well curated by its users, any bad or low quality posts would be removed quickly. Also rep means nothing, sometimes the best of us will ask bad and low quality questions, we are all just humans.

I would go as far as to say, in a spam free world, remove the restrictions and let anyone who needs help get it (that is the stack exchange way, anyone can ask). I could even argue that keeping the entry requirements low also cleans up the main site. People will just spam support questions all over main, if they can't post here. Then someone(s) has to review and migrate them all here anyway.

Anyway, that is just my 2 pence (what happened with that exchange rate?), I hope it helps you with a bit of understanding.